# Как передавать данные из RecyclerView в фрагмент, который открывается по нажатию элементов списка?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть RecyclerView c несколькими элементами, каждый из которых ведет на один и тот же фрагмент. Можно ли через setArguments передавать данные для фрагмента? (например, чтобы при нажатии на разные элементы RecyclerView выводился разный текст). И как это сделать при таком методе создания данных для RecyclerView?

```
    private void prepareData()
{
    SimpleObject item = new SimpleObject(R.drawable.image);
    recyclerList.add(item);

    item = new SimpleObject(R.drawable.image1);
    recyclerList.add(item);

    item = new SimpleObject(R.drawable.image2);
    recyclerList.add(item);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: У вас в чем именно проблема? Вы не знаете как передать информацию из адаптера RV или как правильно передать/получить ее в случае фрагмента?

Comment: как получить знаю, но вот как передать нет через RecyclerView нет

Comment: работа с информацией из `RecyclerView` идёт через адаптер/вьюхолдер. В вашем случае можно так simpleObjectList.get(i/getAdapterPosition()).getImg();. `i`, если используете в `onBind`, `gAP()` - если в холдере

Comment: @Jarvis_J, а как установить для элемента RecyclerView передачу определенного текста? Например первый элемент передает "DataOne', второй "DataTwo" и так далее

Comment: свяжите необходимый текст со списком в адаптере (в классе SimpleObject, из экземпляров которого составлен список, добавьте нужные поля). Либо сделайте в адаптере свой список.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте класс, куда будет добавляться необходимая информация, по типу такого:

```
public class SimpleObject {
    int img;
    String text;

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Передайте список его экземпляров (у вас это `recyclerList`) в свой адаптер.

В адаптере:

Либо:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {    
    viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyFragment mf = MyFragment.newInstance(list.get(i).getText()); //если создаете новый фрагмент  
            или
            mf.setText(list.get(i).getText()) //если фрагмент уже добавлен
        }
    });
}
```

Либо практически то же самое прописываете в холдере:

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyFragment mf = MyFragment.newInstance(list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText()); //если создаете новый фрагмент  
            или
            mf.setText(list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText()) //если фрагмент уже добавлен
        }
    });
```

Вместо `i` используя `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: а если данные должны передаваться в фрагмент на который не ведет RecyclerView (элементы ведут на фрагмент с двумя кнопками, и уже в зависимости от выбранного элемента RecyclerView и нажатой кнопки должен высвечиваться передаваемый текст)

Comment: передавайте информацию из адаптера в активити через интерфейс, пусть активити разбирается, где там что нажато)